# Store Hours: show current open/closed state

Tags: datetime

I'm wanting to do two things [with this great plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/store-hours), but am having a bit of a mind-melt...

1) I'd like to show the current state; e.g. Closing soon; Open now; Closed; Opening Soon

2) I'd like to show the current day highlight:

Sunday:    11:00 AM - 05:00 PM

Monday:    10:00 AM - 08:00 PM

Tuesday:   10:00 AM - 08:00 PM

Wednesday: 10:00 AM - 08:00 PM

**Thursday:  10:00 AM - 08:00 PM**

Friday:    10:00 AM - 08:00 PM

Saturday:  10:00 AM - 07:00 PM

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to point 1)

`{{ location.hours[now|date('w')].open < now and location.hours[now|date('w')].close > now ? 'Open now' : 'Closed' }}`

And that same logic can be used to resolve issue 2)